# CLLocation to work in sleep/screen lock mode (iOs < 4.0)

Tags: iphone, sleep, cllocationmanager

I need to get the user's location even if the phone goes to sleep/screen lock mode. I've tried enabling location services in background mode by adding key to the info.plist file, but this method requires iOS >= 4.0. Is there any alternate method to get the location manager working in screen lock mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Have a look at this:
http://github.com/marcop/iPhoneInsomnia

It keeps the iDevice awake by registering your app as an audioplayer and playing a silent sample every 5 seconds. AFIK, this is the only way to do it in iOS < 4.0.

It seems like a hack, so I don't know what Apple thinks of it, still there are a lot of apps in the AppStore that apparently does this.